# Autoplay iframe YouTube video in Safari 11

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have a simple modal dialog:

- User clicks on button.
- Modal overlay shows.
- YouTube `<iframe>` element is added.

All is good in most browsers - video starts playing, except Safari 11.1.

Safari has new auto-play policy that requires explicit click and video element to start playing it: https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

Is there some way to make it autoplay for dynamically added YouTube (or Vimeo) iframe?

Example YouTube iframe:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media; fullscreen" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/20iMzRklHNU?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

Safari 11 now [disables/blocks autoplay](https://www.howtogeek.com/326532/safari-now-disables-auto-playing-videos.-heres-how-to-allow-them-for-certain-sites/) features. You have to manually go to the safari settings and [Allow All Auto-Play](https://support.apple.com/en-mn/guide/safari/stop-autoplay-videos-ibrw29c6ecf8/mac).